# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cloneNode' of undefined

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to add a duplicate content via clicking the add button, But getting  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cloneNode' of undefined".Whats wrgg>>????

this is the code:

```
  var item = document.getElementById("question")[0];
  var cloneItem = item.cloneNode(true);
  document.body.appendChild(cloneItem);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/syr9vtwx/

Comment: It's `getElementsByTagName` with an _s_ (plural).

Answer (score 2):

you just remove "[0]"

```
var item = document.getElementById("question");
```